# test rest server executeUserSearchRequest returns same transactions

Tags: rest, transactions, yodlee

If I have the max range of 500 then I get different transactions but when I use a smaller range eg 50 I just get the same set of transactions each time.

First call has following parameters and returns transactionIds 10446436 - 10697817

```
{'transactionSearchRequest.firstCall': True,
 'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType': 'ALL_TRANSACTION',
 'userSessionToken': u'08062013_0:7a05db2071f2a15164c45cdec9d2d2edd8a0da26a5d2bd8019d146c1d9b1c5433da9453c2771053f9c1dc0307a7ee59d9249404e63cf47eb49d47ce6e21dacd0',
 'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate': '01-01-2014',
 'transactionSearchRequest.containerType': 'All',
 'transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit': 1,
 'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate': '08-01-2014',
 'transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit': 50,
 'transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput': True,
 'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber': 50,
'cobSessionToken': u'08062013_0:2621954e206e474058f591a32b0facb7e76d03b0aeb904cc2ed31393072ec787fa14fae81dc425f3b61be70f20e19c7fe9dd29ca1092b2189e00f8a7e6fb9a64',
 'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber': 1}
```

Next call returns the same set of 50 transactions when it should return just the 6 not returned before.

```
{'transactionSearchRequest.firstCall': False,
'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType': 'ALL_TRANSACTION',
'userSessionToken': u'08062013_0:7a05db2071f2a15164c45cdec9d2d2edd8a0da26a5d2bd8019d146c1d9b1c5433da9453c2771053f9c1dc0307a7ee59d9249404e63cf47eb49d47ce6e21dacd0',
'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate': '01-01-2014',
'transactionSearchRequest.containerType': 'All', 
'transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit': 51,
'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate': '08-01-2014',
'transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit': 100,
'transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput': True,
'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber': 100, 
'cobSessionToken': u'08062013_0:2621954e206e474058f591a32b0facb7e76d03b0aeb904cc2ed31393072ec787fa14fae81dc425f3b61be70f20e19c7fe9dd29ca1092b2189e00f8a7e6fb9a64',
'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber': 51}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will only work when you have more than 500 transactions for the duration specified.

If you want to get the transactions in chunks then you will have to use [getUserTransaction API](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getUserTransactions) after the call to executeUserSearch.